# Find <li> control from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have li tag. I want to add a class to li from code behind when page index of grid changes. I am using the following code.

Html

```
  <li runat="server" id="tabAssigned" class=""><a href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab">Assigned</a></li>
```

C#

```
         protected void GridAssigned_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridAssigned.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGridAssigned();
        HtmlControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("tabAssigned");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "active");

    }
```

But I am not able to find the li control. Help me do this..

Comment: where's that LI tag Exactly in your markup ?

Comment: <li runat="server" id="tabAssigned" class=""><a href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab">Assigned</a></li>

Comment: have you placed li inside gridview ?? Show us your html markup

Comment: no.. its not inside grid or datalist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your LI has 'runat=server' you should be able to reference it directly as 
tabAssigned.Attributes.Add("class", "active");

That is, as long at it is in the same page, and not in a master/content senario...

Comment: tell me the code if i want to hide or remove class "active" from li

Comment: tabAssigned.Attributes.Remove("class");

Comment: this was simple.. Lol.. I complicated it. @SteinIP Bravo

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

To find the button on your content page you have to search for the ContentPlaceHolder1 control first. Then use the FindControl function on the ContentPlaceHolder1 control to search for your button:

```
 GridAssigned.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindGridAssigned();
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            HtmlControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)cph.FindControl("tabAssigned");
```

Comment: It's not the master page in which i want to find the <li> control.

Answer (score 0):

if you have given runat server property

```
<li runat="server" id="tabAssigned" class=""><a href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab">Assigned</a></li>
```

the the `control is accessible directly by typing the id only` like normal controls

you can play all you want with this control as normal asp.net controls